# Dissolve polygons from layer1 witch overlaps with polygons of layer2 using GRASS

Tags: qgis, geometry, grass-7.0, command-line

I want to dissolve polygons from layer1 witch overlap with polygons of layer2 keeping attributes table of layer1 and using command line.

What I've done :

```
v.in.ogr -o input=original_plygons output=layer1
v.in.ogr -o input=plygons_to_add output=layer2
v.patch -a input=layer2 output=layer1
(v.dissolve input=layer1 output=dissolved column=??? )
```

the problem is to dissolve you should chose a column ! and after the patch (merge) the overlapping polygons of layer2 doesn't have a common same value to dissolve them correctly...

Can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Look at [How to merge adjacent polygons with no common attributes in GRASS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194878/2581)